# Transactions are auto committed on PostgreSQL 9.5.2 with no option to change it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, autocommit

I've just set up a new PostgreSQL 9.5.2, and it seems that all my transactions are auto committed.

Running the following SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
ROLLBACK;
```

results in a warning:

```
WARNING: there is no transaction in progress
ROLLBACK
```

on a **different** transaction, the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test;
```

actually returns the row with `1` (as if the insert was committed).

I tried to set `autocommit` off, but it seems that this feature no longer exists (I get the `unrecognized configuration parameter` error).

What the hell is going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

autocommit in Postgres is controlled by the SQL *client*, not on the server.

In `psql` you can do this using

```
\set AUTOCOMMIT off
```

Details are in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES

In that case **every** statement you execute starts a transaction until you run `commit` (including `select` statements!)

Other SQL clients have other ways of enabling/disabling autocommit.

---

Alternatively you can use `begin` to start a transaction manually.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-begin.html

```
psql (9.5.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> \set AUTCOMMIT on
postgres=> begin;
BEGIN
postgres=> create table test (id integer);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> insert into test values (1);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=> rollback;
ROLLBACK
postgres=> select * from test;
ERROR:  relation "test" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from test;
                      ^
postgres=>
```

Comment: The `\set` command doesn't seem to affect anything. The `begin` does. Seems like a bug to me. I'm using `psql` on Windows 10.

Comment: `\set AUTCOMMIT off` most definitively works. Did you maybe use lowercase? Variable names in `psql` are case sensitive.

Comment: Yeah, it works; it's case sensitive (why there's no error when I get it wrong, though?). Is there anyway to set the client to load with a default auto-commit off setting?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES) "*If you prefer autocommit-off, you might wish to set it in the system-wide psqlrc file or your ~/.psqlrc file*". Details about the psqlrc file [are also in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html#AEN96655)

Comment: To check if autocommit has been set: `\echo :AUTOCOMMIT` https://stackoverflow.com/a/41298374/5986661

Answer (score 2):

```
\set AUTCOMMIT 'off';
```

The `off value` should be in single quotes

Comment: Typo! I've lost 'O' :(

Answer (score 1):

This should work. `\set AUTOCOMMIT` off. See the example below.

```
account_dept=# \set AUTOCOMMIT off
account_dept=# update account set ACCT_BALANCE= acct_balance + 200 WHERE ACCT_NUM=1;
UPDATE 1
account_dept=# rollback;
```