# How to check if autocommit is on or not postgres' psql

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line, psql, autocommit

I'm using postgres 9.5. How can I check if auto commit is on or off? I tried `SHOW AUTOCOMMIT` where I got `ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "autocommit"` then I did a `\set autocommit off` and then `SHOW AUTOCOMMIT` gives me blank output. How can identify if autocommit is on or off? Also can I set it to off while/after the database in created in my sql file?

Comment: Good question. Autocommit seems to be always ON and I also got the same messages when I tried to see setting. PG 9.4 was at least showing text that autocommit cannot be set to OFF. But 9.5 and 9.6 gives this error although documentation still contains set and show autocommit commands.

Comment: yeah in postgres auto commit is on by default. we can switch it off using `\set AUTOCOMMIT off`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/autocommit-in-postgresqls-psql) Dustin Marx article, you can use:

```
\echo :AUTOCOMMIT
```

> If it's desired to "always" have autocommit disabled, the \set
>   AUTOCOMMIT off meta-command can be added to one's local ~/.psqlrc
>   file. For an even more global setting, this meta-command can be placed
>   in apsqlrc file in the database's system config directory (which can
>   be located using PostgreSQL operating system-level command pg_config
>   --sysconfdir).

Comment: Thanks. what is the best place to set it off permanently? In my application I have a sql file  where I create the database. Should I set it off there?

Comment: I got `You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.` when I did `pg_config --sysconfdir`

Comment: @love2code: put the `set` statement into `~/.psqlrc` as mentioned in the answer

Comment: I did try that. cat ~/.psqlrc gives `--
--      system-wide psql configuration file
--
--  This file is read before the .psqlrc file in the user's home directory.
--
--  Copy this to your installation's sysconf directory and rename it psqlrc.
--  The sysconf directory can be identified via "pg_config --sysconfdir".
--
\set AUTOCOMMIT off` logged out and logged in again but `echo :AUTOCOMMIT` is always on.

Comment: I guess the error is in using `\set` in the .psqlrc - it should be plain `set autocommit = off`

Comment: I think `set autocommit = off` in .psqlrc only works in older versions.

Comment: Works great on Postgres 14. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With **the command** below on **psql**, you can check if **AUTOCOMMIT** is `on` or `off`. ***AUTOCOMMIT** must be **uppercase**:

```
\echo :AUTOCOMMIT
```

This is if **AUTOCOMMIT** is `on`:

```
postgres=# \echo :AUTOCOMMIT
on
```

This is if **AUTOCOMMIT** is `off`:

```
postgres=# \echo :AUTOCOMMIT
off
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way is to just execute commit; and look for the below message to infer auto-commit is on or not.

Error report -
SQL Error: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.

Note: I used SQL developer so not sure about other IDEs